# Modal View Does Not Appear in Center in Horizontal Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIPresentationFormSheet (contains a textview) that appears in the center of the screen when I am in vertical orientation. When I dismiss the modal view, it disappears fine.

When I am in horizontal orientation my modal view does not appear in the center of the screen. I have to dismiss my keyboard for the modal view to appear in the center.

```
[self presentModalViewController:composeTweetController animated:TRUE];
```

When I dismiss the modal view in horizontal orientation the app automatically switches to vertical orientation.

```
-(void)dismissComposeTweetView{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

The modal view controller supports horizontal orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

I want the following to happen:

1. Modal view should appear in the center in horizontal orientation
2. Modal view should disappear without switching to vertical orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the modal view controller have an appropriate override of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`?

Comment: Looks like I needed to implement shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrinetation for the view controller that presented the modal view.